# how to correctly create those models in django?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-schema

Good day. I'm trying to write an app which will ask a car seller to register himself and his shop name along with a password. On the other side, I would like a buy, to register himself using his a username and password. 
The user will be able to login, chose a car model catalogue and then can buy.
But I'm facing an issue with the models design.
Here are my models:

```
class ShopOwner(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Buyer(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username 

class Shop(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(ShopOwner)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Class Catalogue(models.Model):
     shop = models.ManyToManyField(Shop)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
     catalogue = ManyToManyField(Catalogue)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

I will appreciate any advise on this.

Comment: What issue are you facing with?

Comment: @FLICKER I'm about to start implementing, but had many issues with the many to many relation in the past, I wanted some advises on the models, are they corrects?